# Practicing in Postman API testing and test failing because of an Assertion Error

Tags: javascript, api, rest, postman

I am making a post request to create a user on a practice api and unfortunately I continue to get a failure when I inititate my test, in particular 'AssertionError: expected '405' to be a number'. I dont understand where I am going wrong.

```
console.log(pm.response.json())

pm.test("Successful POST request", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([201, 202]);
});

bodyData = pm.response.json()

console.log(bodyData)

pm.test("ID is created", () => {
    pm.expect(bodyData.id).to.be.a("number");
})
```

I expected the test to pass because it would take the respone data within the body, in particular the ID that is provided when you create a user, because this is a number, I structured my test to pass around the assertion of a number being present at this part of the response body

Comment: Could you add response to your question? it's not enough info to say where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Someone responded to my question and gave me the solution, he told me to check if the id was a string instead of a number and that solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).